# Excel - Converting DOB to something easier to understand

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I hope you are having a good day.

I have a DOB in the form of yy/mm/dd. Where the dob is 071018 I want to excel to realize that it's the 18th of October 2007 and if instead the dob is 980819 then 19th of August 1998.

I have tried:

```
=TEXT(DATE(IF(LEFT(F2,1)="0",2000,1900) + 
  VALUE(LEFT(F2,2)), VALUE(MID(F2,4,2)), 
  VALUE(RIGHT(F2,2)), "d/m/yyyy")
```

But excel throws 'You've entered too many arguments for this function'.
Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Since your year only has two digits, you need to decide where you want to change from the 1900's to the 2000's.

In your formula, you are effectively making that change at `10`. In other words, a date like `100505` will be converted to `05-May-1910`. This may be what you want.

Here is a formula that gives you more control over when you want the century to change:
*Note that the formula will work whether the date is entered as a text string or as a number*.

This outputs the date as a "real date" which can be formatted in Excel.

```
=LET(
    d, TEXT(A1, "000000"),
    y, LEFT(d, 2) + 1900 +
        (--LEFT(d, 2) < 40) * 100,
    m, MID(d, 3, 2),
    dy, RIGHT(d, 2),
    DATE(y, m, dy)
)
```

To output as a text string, you can use:

```
=LET(
    d, TEXT(A1, "000000"),
    y, LEFT(d, 2) + 1900 +
        (--LEFT(d, 2) < 40) * 100,
    m, MID(d, 3, 2),
    dy, RIGHT(d, 2),
    TEXT(DATE(y, m, dy), "dd/mm/yyyy")
)
```

I chose the 40th year, but you can alter that so that your latest possible year will get converted correctly.

The above is for MS365 so you can see the logic easily. Note that this will work whether your data is entered as a text string or as a number.

If you do not have the `LET`, the formula can be re-written.

Comment: Very nice formula, very nice, any layman/amateur can understand, the formula clearly explains, helps to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I added an if statement.

```
=TEXT(DATE(IF(LEFT(A1,1)="0",2000,1900)+LEFT(A1,2),MID(A1,3,2),RIGHT(A1,2)),"dd/mm/yyyy")
```